# Multilple Images Texture

Tags: texturing, image

how can i add another layer of another image texture(in this case a PNG image) onto an object that already has an image texture on it?

for example: i use a plane as a floor and it has a wooden texture on it but now i want to add a dirt PNG on it as well.

Comment: Hint: mix color node.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that , grab those image textures and mix those with a mix rgb node . Then set the mix mode to multiply and factor to 1. In case it's a png image then don't forget to use alpha as factor. Alpha value won't work in eevee . So set the blend mode to alpha hashed.

Hope that helps.